Indecomposability of an object, in the bounded derived category of finitely generated modules, whose derived self-Hom is isomorphic to the ring
Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring. Let $M\in \mathcal D^b(\text{mod } R)$  be such that $\mathbf R \text {Hom}_R(M, M)\cong R$. Then, is $M$ indecomposable in $\mathcal D^b(\text{mod } R)$ ?
Thoughts: If $M$ were actually  in the subcategory $\text{mod } R$, then comparing homologies, we actually get $\text{Hom}_R(M, M)\cong R$ is a local ring, hence $M$ is indecomposable.

Yes. In any additive category, if the endomorphism ring of an object $M$ is a local ring, then $M$ is indecomposable.
Now, if $M \in D^b(\text{mod} \;R)$ is such that $R\text{Hom}_R(M,M)\cong R$ (i.e., cohomologically concentrated in degree $0$ with cohomology $R$), then $\text{Hom}_{D^b(\text{mod} R)}(M,M)=H^0(R\text{Hom}_R(M,M))\cong R$, hence local.
